# Cannot access WP admin because plugin returns 204

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, headers

I recently installed a plugin on my schools wordpress site that one of my friends wrote, that should pull the newest video from a youtube page and post it. If the video hasn't changed, he set up the plugin to return a `HTTP/1.0 204` code. However, this seems to have rendered the wp-admin unavailable, as when I try to access it, it seems the plugins are also loaded, and so I get a `204` header when I try to access the admin panel.

Is there any way to circumvent the plugins loading or something similar so I can access the wp-admin panel to disable the plugin, or will I have to use phpMyAdmin to go in and manually disable all installed plugins in the `wp_options` table?

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to disable a plugin is to rename the offending plugin's directory, and it'll be disabled on next page load.